# How to call a function in .c file from .m or .swift files in ios?

Tags: ios, c, swift, xcode6.1, hidapi

here my question was, i have a `.swift` file and i have `.c` ('C' file) with some functions. I want to call those functions from `.swift` file how can i do that?

Example:

In my `product.c` file i have this function

```
static unsigned short get_vendor_id(IOHIDDeviceRef device)
{
    return get_long_property(device, CFSTR(kIOHIDVendorIDKey));
}
```

Now how can i import this `product.c` file in my `viewcontroller.swift` and how to call this `get_vendor_id method` from `.switf`  and how to take the return value?

First of all is it possible?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002369/how-to-call-objective-c-code-from-swift 

It is given clearly in the above link!

Comment: AMAN77 Also gave same answer. Thanks